# How to prevent menu bar from wrapping?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

Using Tkinter 8.6 in Python 3.6 on Windows 10, at the moment my root form is rather narrow causing the menu bar to wrap. Is there a way to prevent wrapping? In this particular case, increasing the form width to accommodate the menu is acceptable behavior.

The problem with wrapping is the geometry manager does not compensate - the grid, for instance, will have controls partially out of view since the window is not automatically resized to account for the extra menu height.

Actual:
[image: menu wrapping]

Expected:
[image: menu no wrapping]

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: It would also help us to know what platform you are running on.

Comment: See my comment regarding code sample on your answer.

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your results. I can create a menubar that wraps, and I can add an image using `grid`, and those widgets accommodate the wrapped menubar just fine. Enough space is reserved below the menubar for the image. There must be a bug in your code, but without seeing your code it's impossible to know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to prevent wrapping. The menubar is not under the control of tkinter.

Grid will compensate just fine as long as you don't explicitly set the window size to something smaller than will fit the wrapped menu and your contents. If you aren't setting the window size, and grid isn't compensating, then you need to show an example that illustrates that.

Comment: The pictures demonstrate no window size and the grid - i.e., geometry manager - not compensating.

Comment: @IAbstract: I have no idea what you mean by the picture demonstrating no window size. Clearly the windows have a size.

Comment: The grid geometry manager sizes the container and thus the window. Do you understand how the grid geometry manager works?

Comment: I'll take the answer you give in your first sentence. Any code sample I give will be contrived and inaccurate due to my specific case otherwise I would have provided the 3 lines to replicate the issue.